# jQuery, how do I get the position of a select?

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to get the value of whatever date (1-12) gets chosen in a select statement.

the select:

```
    <select id="month"></select>
```

gets populated with this:

```
    $(function(){
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "lib/getmonth.php",
            async: "false",
            success: function(response){
                var monthArry = response.split(",");
                for(var x=0; x < [monthArry.length-1]; x++){
                    $("#month").append("<option>" + monthArry[x] + "</option>");
                }
            }
        });
    });
```

I'm at a loss here, I can obviously get the name,

```
    var month = $("#month").val();
```

but I'm not sure how to pick up on the which 'option' is selected?

Comment: If you are going to iterate, then cache the `$("#month")` so that you don't search for it each time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [:selected](http://api.jquery.com/selected-selector/) selector:

```
var selectedOption = $("#month option:selected");
```

**EDIT:** If you're looking for the inner text of the selected option, you can apply [text()](http://api.jquery.com/text/) to the result:

```
var selectedOptionText = $("#month option:selected").text();
```

And if you want its one-based index, you can add `1` to the value returned by [index()](http://api.jquery.com/index/) :

```
var selectedMonth = $("#month option:selected").index() + 1;
```

Comment: this alerts "[object Object]"?

Comment: @Brendan, yes, because `selectedOption` is a jQuery object. Your question seems to imply you're looking for the selected `<option>` element, or did I misunderstand?

Answer (score 0):

It is working for me [jsfiidle](http://jsfiddle.net/3yu4p/).

simplified success method.

```
success: function(response){
       $("#month").append('<option>' +  response.split(",").join("</option><option>") + "</option>");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to know the index of the selected `option`:

```
var selectedOption = $('#month option:selected').index();
```

Or, using plain JavaScript:

```
var selectedOption = document.getElementById('month').selectedIndex;
```